# How to test api using Mockito? Do we need to mock all the class variables?

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, mockito

I want to test an API which uses so many class variables, and also in the method there are so many others method calls, I don't know how to mock them all or do I need a different approach.

Please help me fix this, I am providing the code below:

```
public class LoginController implements Initializable
```

{

```
protected static BorderPane choose;

protected static VBox menu;

@FXML
private BorderPane loginPane;

@FXML
private Label errorText;

@FXML
private PasswordField password;

@FXML
private Label databaseName;

@FXML
private Label host;

@FXML
private Button login;

@FXML
private TextField userId;

BaseFrame mainController = BaseFrame.getMainController();

@Override
public void initialize(URL arg0, ResourceBundle arg1)
{
    assert login != null : "fx:id=\"login\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'Login.fxml'.";
    OSSDatabase ossDatabase = (OSSDatabase) OSSConfigurationTool.getContext().getBean("ossDatabase");
    this.databaseName.setText(ossDatabase.getName());
    this.host.setText(ossDatabase.getHost());
    login.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>()
    {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event)
        {
            String username = userId.getText().trim();
            String credentials = password.getText().trim();
            if (isValid(username) && isValid(credentials))
            {
                errorText.setText("");
                UserManager userManager = (UserManager) OSSConfigurationTool.getContext().getBean("UserManager");
                try
                {
                    userManager.login(username, credentials, true);
                    FXMLLoader menuLoader = new FXMLLoader(LoginController.class.getResource("/com/capsilon/oss/configuration/tool/view/mainMenu.fxml"));
                    try
                    {
                        mainController.getMenuPane().setVisible(true);
                        mainController.getMenuPane().add((VBox) menuLoader.load(), 0, 1);
                    } catch (IOException e)
                    {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } catch (OSSException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    errorText.setText(e.getErrorCode().name());
                    errorText.setTooltip(new Tooltip(e.getMessage()));
                }
            }
            else
            {
                errorText.setText("Username or Password is empty");
            }
        }
    });
}
```

}

While creating test for this method, I have written the following test method which initially gives NPE and doesn't proceeds further.

```
public class LoginControllerTest 
{
@Mock
OSSDatabase ossDatabase;
@Mock
private TextField userId;
@Mock
private PasswordField password;

LoginController controller = new LoginController();

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception 
{
}

@Test
public final void testInitialize() 
{
    URL url = PowerMockito.mock(URL.class);
    ResourceBundle bundle = Mockito.mock(ResourceBundle.class);

    Mockito.when((OSSDatabase) OSSConfigurationTool.getContext().getBean("ossDatabase")).thenReturn(ossDatabase);
    Mockito.when(ossDatabase.getName()).thenReturn("SomeName");
    Mockito.when(ossDatabase.getHost()).thenReturn("SomeHost");
    Mockito.when(userId.getText().trim()).thenReturn("userName");

    controller.initialize(url, bundle);
}
```

}

Although I have stubbed some method calls, still confused whether this is the right way or not. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Consider your difficulty as a code smell, that the class is doing too much. Separating the business/database procedures from the view manipulation procedures may make each half easier to test.

Comment: Agreed. You definitely want to separate concerns, that's one of the goal of object oriented programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't say where is your NPE...

i think it was here :

```
((OSSDatabase) OSSConfigurationTool.getContext()
```

when you get the context no?

if yes, you have to mock OSSConfigurationTool.getContext() to return a context ;)

if OSSConfigurationTool is a static call you have to use (in junit > 4)

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest( OSSConfigurationTool.class )   
public class LoginControllerTest {
...
```

add this line too if needed

```
PowerMockito.mockStatic(OSSConfigurationTool.class);
```

try  all of this and let me know if its work

thanks

Comment: Right. I need to mock the call OSSConfigurationTool.getContext() and then stub methods being called on it. Thanks, it helped me.